# how to solve ApcCache requires PHP apcu extension to be loaded

Tags: php

Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
ApcCache requires PHP apcu extension to be loaded.

Comment: This question is more suitable for [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: There is no such thing as "Ubuntu 20"

Comment: Also, apc is considered dead - the most recent version was released in 2012. Why not use apcu?

Comment: Please do not simply change your question to a completely different once, especially if you don't ask any question at all

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it solved by running the command bellow
sudo apt-get install php8.1-apc